# How can I get a hyphenated class name from a resource in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, how do I go from a resource to a string containing its class name stylized with hyphens (as in a CSS class name)? I'd like a method `#hyphenated_class_name` or the like that I can apply to ActiveRecord resource of, say, class `MyResource`, and get back `my-resource`.

Answer (score 12):

You're probably looking for `underscore` or `dasherize` methods, from ActiveSupport::Inflector. You need both to go from a class name to hyphenated string:

```
> PrettyPrint::SingleLine.name.demodulize.underscore.dasherize
=> "single-line"
```

Comment: Underscore doesn't appear to imitate what Rails helpers traditionally tend to do in that they convert namespace `::` delimiters to slashes rather than underscores.

Comment: ActiveSupport::Inflector.to_s.underscore for example will return "active_support/inflector" - you need to convert to String before calling the underscore method.

Comment: I verified this is correct: `require 'active_support/inflector'; 'MyClass'.underscore.dasherize`. Note that `underscore` is required for `dasherize` to work